# Run individual Jest unit test for Angular 16+ with ng test

Tags: angular, intellij-idea, jestjs

Last week we updated from Angular 15 to Angular 16 in our project. Our previous Jest config with jest-preset-angular now uses the built-in experimental Jest support.

Two relevant changes we did:

1. We've added the following to our `angular.json`:

   ```
   "test": {
     "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:jest",
     "options": {
       "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
       "polyfills": [
         "zone.js",
         "zone.js/testing"
       ]
     }
   }
   ```
2. `"test": "jest --silent"` is changed to `"test": "ng test"` in our package.json scripts.

When we run all our unit tests at once with `ng test` or `npm test`, everything works as expected.

However, when we try to run an individual test in IntelliJ, it gives unrelated errors. I'm pretty sure this is because it still tries to run the unit test as `jest` instead of `@angular-devkit/build-angular:jest`.

When I look in the Run Configuration of the Jest unit test I see the following for Jest package: `...\node_modules\jest`.
How can I change this to the Jest that `@angular-devkit/build-angular` uses? Or is there something else I should change, in order to run an individual Jest unit test in IntelliJ with the new Angular 16 experimental Jest support?

---

Update: I tried the suggested changes of *@Oksana* in the first comment:

- `jest` is changed to `jest:run` on line `"builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:jest",` of our `angular.json`
- The run config is modified to use `...\node_modules\@angular\cli` instead of `...\node_modules\jest`

I also use IntelliJ version 2023.1.2 (Ultimate Edition).

But unfortunately I now get the following error when I run a test (with that modified run config):

> Test framework quit unexpectedly
> Error: Unknown arguments: colors, reporters, verbose

Here is also a screenshot of the current run config:

[image]

Comment: It works in 2023.1.2 with "...\node_modules\@angular\cli" as Jest package in the run configuration and `"builder": "@angular-builders/jest:run"` in angular.json.

Comment: @Oksana Thank you. I'll test your proposed solution this upcoming Monday when I'm at the office again, and will let you know the result. If it works, I'll lyk so you can make this comment into an answer for me to accept (and upvote). :)

Comment: @Oksana That alone doesn't seem to work, since I now get an error `Error: Unknown arguments: colors, reporters, verbose, test-name-pattern, test-path-pattern`. (I also use IntelliJ 2023.1.2 Ultimate Edition.) I've updated the question with a screenshot of my new run config after your suggested change.

Comment: Currently on the same issue. What @Oksana proposed i believe is the right direction. But the issue is the additional arguments that webstorm passes to the command (such as `--colors` and `--reporters`). Is there an update on the topic?

Comment: @ilpianoforte I ran into the same issue. I created an anomaly on YouTrack hopefully they resolve it soon. I imagine it shouldn't be too difficult of a change for them to make

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this with two steps.

1. Install `@angular-builders/jest` if not using latest version of angular you may want to specify the version ie if on angular 16 run `npm install @angular-builders/jest@16` otherwise just a `npm install @angular-builders/jest` will be enough
2. update the test.builder in angular.json config to use `@angular-builders/jest:run`

my final angular.json test config looks as follows:

```json
"test": {
  "builder": "@angular-builders/jest:run",
  "options": {
    "polyfills": [
      "zone.js",
      "zone.js/testing"
    ],
    "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json"
  }
}
```